# Multiple locking task (threading)

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety

I need to implement the class that should perform locking mechanism in our framework. 
We have several threads and they are numbered 0,1,2,3.... We have a static class called `ResourceHandler`, that should lock these threads on given objects. The requirement is that n `Lock()` invokes should be realeased by m `Release()` invokes, where n = [0..] and m = [0..]. So no matter how many locks was performed on single object, only one `Release()`  call is enough to unlock all. Even further if o object is not locked, `Release()` call should perform nothing. Also we need to know what objects are locked on what threads.

I have this implementation:

```
public class ResourceHandler
{
    private readonly Dictionary<int, List<object>> _locks = new Dictionary<int, List<object>>();

    public static ResourceHandler Instance {/* Singleton */}

    public virtual void Lock(int threadNumber, object obj)
    {
        Monitor.Enter(obj);

        if (!_locks.ContainsKey(threadNumber)) {_locks.Add(new List<object>());}
        _locks[threadNumber].Add(obj);
    }

    public virtual void Release(int threadNumber, object obj)
    {
       // Check whether we have threadN in _lock and skip if not
       var count = _locks[threadNumber].Count(x => x == obj);
       _locks[threadNumber].RemoveAll(x => x == obj);

       for (int i=0; i<count; i++)
       {
           Monitor.Exit(obj);
       }
    }

    // .....
 }
```

Actually what I am worried here about is thread-safety. I'm actually not sure, is it thread-safe or not, and it's a real pain to fix that. Am I doing the task correctly and how can I ensure that this is thread-safe?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand : one thread is supposed to stop another or is threadN the number of current thread?

Comment: threadN is the number of the current thread. Lock and Release should lock and release thread as Monitor.Enter/Exit is doing that, but the rule about many locks - many releases should be satisfied. Also I need to count objects, that are locked and know their thread numbers (we have some clean-up for each thread, where we can release all the objects in finally block to ensure that all the locks are release when the application is halted)

Comment: I have changed threadN to threadNumber

Comment: Why are you writing your own locking class, is there somthing wrong with the built in ones?

Comment: @Jodrell The built one doesn't support requirement "one release" releases "many locks" and release of not-locked object is doing nothing. It is a requirement of the customer, and even I'm not sure why do we need that, I need to do it. And also I need to count locked objects with their thread numbers

Comment: @Archeg, can you find another customer? (<g>)

Comment: @MartinJames too bad they are paying me enough money to not consider such solution :D Actually as we are writing the framework and the customer will use it, it is pretty reasonable for the customer to ask some internal-architecture stuff

Comment: @Archeg - I'm sorry if I was a bit 'flippant', but this requirement just looks like one of those designed to make multiThreading as awkward and difficult as possible:( There is a plus side - if you are forced to implement this, you can look forward to years of lucrative support/maintenance work..  I will actually think about your requirement to see if I can think of a way of 'sanitizing' it.

Comment: @MartinJames Yes, it's ok :) I think I will definetly discuss this with the customer. I was asked to check all the ways we can do that without directly involving him, and only if I prove that it's stupid to do such stuff, I will have a green light to open that question on the upper level

Comment: Well, I could not apply the 'stupid' tag without a deeper knowledge of the system that you could probably not post online anyway 'cos of NDA etc. I will say, however, that thread micro-management such as is suggested would be an absolute last resort for me and, if it was offered to me as a contract job, I would turn it down. Every time I see a complex locking scheme that locks anything for longer than the time taken to push/pop an object to a queue, I get the jitters and an uncontrollable urge to update my CV.

Comment: @MartinJames It is possible that I am using synchronization not in the proper way. Let's say I have several threads and each thread is working with some hardware. But there is a problem: there is one block of HW, that is shared, and because of that cannot be used simultaneosly. We are using these locks here. Yes, they are long-termed, but I don't see any other way how to do that.

Comment: I have a similar issue with the SD-card on my embedded job, but worse - there is only enough RAM for one thread/stack to make disk calls, whereas several threads need disk access.  What I do is have all the threads descend from some class and, if they need disk, they make a diskRequest() call that queues them to the SD-card handler thread and then waits on a private semaphore. The card-thread gets them and calls back to an inherited 'diskhandler' method which performs open/read/write/.. on the card-thread stack.  When done, the semaphore is signaled and the requster runs, its disk op done.

Comment: Some may say that queueing request-objects to one hardware-handler thread is just an over-complicated lock.  Yes.. and no. Threads have the option of queueing up multiple requests and having them all signaled when done - no lock-wait for each.  Debugging is easy - I can see what disk requests are queued up and watch them executed in a serial manner.  The disk-handler thread input queue has two concurrent queues with one semaphore, so forming a priority queue - requests from the main dispenser system are processed before a file-copy request from the command-line interpreter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Lock` method locks on the target `object`s but the `_locks` dictionary can be accessed by any thread at any time. You may want to add a private lock object for accessing the dictionary (in both the `Lock` and `Release` methods).

Also keep in mind that by using such a ResourceHandler it is the responsibility of the rest of the code (the consuming threads) to release all used objects (a regular `lock ()` block for instance covers that problem since whenever you leave the `lock`'s scope, the object is released).

You also may want to use `ReferenceEquals` when counting the number of times an object is locked instead of `==`.

Comment: Placing a lock is a problem. For example I cannot place a lock() {} inside of the Lock() method, as there is already Monitor.Enter() and we will receive a deadlock. And about releasing - yes, that is one of the reasons why am I need to count all the locked objects and their thread numbers

Comment: You should not include the `Monitor` calls inside the lock, just the access to the dictionary. Deadlocks will occur when threads lock on more than one object at a time and not always in the same order.

Comment: In that case I have a problem with code like in my Release method. I have code that counts locks, and returns the count variable. And I need to perform as many releases as this count variable. I can wrap the dictionary usage into lock, but I still have this count variable unsafe

Comment: The `count` variable is a local variable so it cannot be referenced by other threads. Since the object the count is for is still locked by the current thread, no other threads can lock it so no other threads can store the value into the dictionary during the `count` loop.

Comment: PS. why not lock on an object only if the object was not owned by the current thread already, and keep track of the times the lock method was called, without locking it consecutive times?

Comment: hm.. Good point about count. Need to think of it. About locking only once - sure I can do that. But I guess it doesn't make any difference. Count will become some boolean flag, but still it is a bottleneck

Comment: Count variable in that case can be unsafe if two threads will invoke Release with the same threadNumber. This is not a requirement that to be a stupid-proof, but the customer could want that as we are writing the framework. But I guess I can resolve that somehow, thinking further....

Comment: I assumed the threadNumber would be the number of the thread invoking `Release`?

Comment: yep, but in our current design (I'm trying to convince guys to change that, but we have very strict design described by one guy that is located in other country) the user who will use the framework is specifying this number by hisown, so theoretically he can make a mistake.

Comment: If he does make a mistake, thread A could call `Monitor.Exit` for objects locked by thread B, causing thread B to not be able to release his locks anymore.

Comment: Good point. I guess one more point to why these requirement should be reconsidered

Answer (score 1):

You can ensure this class is thread safe by using a [ConcurrentDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191.aspx) but, it won't help you with all the problems you will get from trying to develop your own locking mechanism.

There are a number locking mechansims that are already part of the .Net Framework, you should use those.

It sounds like you are going to need to use a combination of these, including [Wait Handles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228962.aspx) to achieve what you want.

---

**EDIT**

After reading more carefully, I think you might need an [`EventWaitHandle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.eventwaithandle.aspx)

Comment: Can you suggest some that fit my requirement?

Comment: Still not sure how to do that with events. I've spend the whole yesterday trying to use them here. It looks quite complicated

Answer (score 1):

What you have got conceptually looks dangerous; this is bacause calls to `Monitor.Enter` and `Monitor.Exit` for them to work as a `Lock` statement, are reccomended to be encapsulated in a `try/finally` block, that is to ensure they are executed sequetally. Calling `Monitor.Exit` before `Monitor.Enter` will throw an exception.

To avoid these problems (if an exception is thrown, the lock for a given thread may-or-may-not be taken, and if a lock is taken it will not be released, resulting in a leaked lock. I would recomend using one of the options provided in the other answers above. However, if you do want to progress with this mechanism, CLR 4.0 added the following overload to the `Monitor.Enter` method

```
public static void Enter (object, ref bool lockTaken);
```

`lockTaken` is false if and only if the `Enter` method throws an exception and the lock was not taken. So, using your two methods using a global `bool` `lockTaken` you can create something like (here the example is for a single locker - you will need a Dictionary of `List<bool>` corresponding to your threads - or event better a `Tuple`). So in your method `Lock` you would have something like

```
bool lockTaken = false;
Monitor.Enter(locker, ref lockTaken);
```

in the other method `Release`

```
if (lockTaken)
    Monitor.Exit(locker);
```

I hope this helps.

*Edit: I don't think I fully appreciate your problem, but from what I can gather I would be using a [Concurrent Collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.concurrent). These are fully thead safe. Check out `IProducerConsumerCollection<T>` and `ConcurrentBag<T>`. These should facilitate what you want with all thread safter taken care of by the framework (note. a thread safe collection doesn't mean the code it executes is thread safe!). However, using a collection like this, is likely to be far slower than using locks.*

Comment: I can ensure that all the locks are released by enumerating my dictionary and releasing the locks at the end of the thread (actually every thread has finally block with that). This overload looks quite nice, and I was trying to use it, but still not sure how to achive full thread-safety here. I need to calculate how many times Lock method was called - that means that I have a dictionary or list that is not thread-safe. And even if I use ConcurrentDictionary, I still have some thread-unsafe code, like enumerating the dictionary and calling releases

Comment: I have added a small edit with come other concurrent collections to look at. With the above I am sayng that for each `locker` include a lockTaken in the `Dictonary/Tuple`, then you add to the tuple the count AND whether the lock is taken or not. This will ensure you are not releasing locks that have not been 'taken'. Good luck...

Answer (score 0):

IMO you need to use atomic set of functions to make it safe.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex.aspx

Mutexes I guess will help u.

Comment: I want to know all the hills and falls of this problem. I'm using Monitor now, isn't it an atomic operation? I do not need inter-process locking, so I guess Monitor should do the same as Mutex in my situation

Comment: Yes you right. Monitor is what you need. To make sure run extensive test over weekend with thousand threads under profiler. To make sure you implemented everything fine. Some stress testing.